# How to fix empty href attribute when page in browser is on /Identity/Account/Register

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net core 2.1 mvc web application with Identity. On the layout page I have a link like this: `<a asp-area="Main" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">`. When I am on the main page the link works as expected and reloads the main page. However when I go to any of the Identity pages and inspect the link in Chrome Developer Tools it only shows `<a href>`.

I moved all my code other than Identity to another Area, called Main.

After creating a new minimal project as suggested in the answer below, the minimal app works as expected. However I cannot find the cause of the problem when checking my main app. What I have done so far:

Here is the folder structure for the Main area:

[image: Main Area Structure]

Here is the Area attribute for the Home Controller:

```
namespace catchme.bg.Areas.Main.Controllers
{
    [Area("Main")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {`
```

Here is the routing config in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapAreaRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    areaName: "Main",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            });
```

Here is the link in the _Layout.cshtml file in the Views/Shared folder:

```
<a asp-area="Main" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MainIndex</a>
```

The contents of the _ViewImports.cshtml file in the Views folder is like so:

```
@using catchme.bg
@using catchme.bg.Models
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
```

And the contents of the _ViewImports.cshtml file in the Areas\Identity\Pages folder is

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using catchme.bg.Areas.Identity
@namespace catchme.bg.Areas.Identity.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I would like to be able to go to the start page when I click the link in the main layout, no matter which page is opened at the moment.

What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Eis! It's very hard to understand what's going wrong without seeing an [mcve] of your code. Making a question easy to answer is a lot of work, and often takes more than 15 minutes. On the plus side, sometimes, you'll solve your problem alone just by making an MCVE.

Comment: What do you mean by `I moved all my code other than Identity to another Area, called Main.`. Check my answer, I fail to reproduce your issue and share us the difference.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and suggestions to make a MCVE. I will do that, but in the mean time I wanted to clarify that I moved the controllers and the views from the root folder to a folder named Main, added area attributes to the controllers in this folder and changed the Startup.cs similar to what is shown in the answer below. I will need some time to sort things out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hello again! After following the steps in the answer from @tao-zhou the sample application works just fine. For the life of me I cannot find a difference from my project and the sample application when it comes to creating an area and setting the correct routes. On the _Layout.cshtml page I used the same link as in the answer below, which in my case results in <a href></a> tag when I view source and I am in the Identity area. On the home page /Main everything works fine. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the issue described here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8072

Comment: Finally, I found  where the problem is. I had the following line in Startup.cs    app.UseMvc(); before app.UseMvc(routes => { ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow steps below to achieve your requirement.

1. Create Asp.Net Core MVC 2.1 project with Identity.
2. Create a folder named `Main` under `Areas`
3. Move `Controllers`, `Data`, `Models` and `Views` to Main Folder
4. Change Layout to add `<li><a asp-area="Main" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MainIndex</a></li>`
5. Change `Startup.cs` with

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       routes.MapRoute(
               name: "areas",
               template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   ```
6. Run Project to check the result.

Comment: I found an answer on SO that led me to include the following as a default route: `routes.MapAreaRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    areaName: "Main",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` Now it works fine. Thanks!